# How to clear Linkedin Share cache?

Tags: social-networking, linkedin-api

I have a new description in the page but when I share the page it is still using the old description that no longer exists, I am after something similar like the Facebook Lint.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

You can append dummy query string value to your url and make it look like a new url and LinkedIn fetches it again. I've tried it and it works.

For example:

https://www.codeproof.com/**?refid=LinkedIn**

where refid=LinkedIn is just a dummy value.

If your url already contains query string and then just append "&refid=LinkedIn" at the end of the url.

Comment: Has anyone had any success with this approach? Not working for me so far.

Comment: doesn't work for me. I have a client asking for the update and LinkedIn keeps showing the old image, title and description

Comment: Worked for me. I was trying to delint the thumbnail for a Behance project. Adding simply `&1` forced it nicely. Wish they had a delinter tool like Facebook offers.

Comment: This worked great for me. To reiterate, you are basically tricking linkedin into thinking its accessing a new URL so it can parse for open graph tags as if it is the first time your site is being shared.

Comment: And you can also, purge cache in your backend, and Both worked for me.

Comment: 2018 and this trick still works. Unfortunately had to visit LinkedIn site to check, so expecting a flood of new emails atsn

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, appending a query string to the URL **no longer works**.

From the following StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985659/how-to-update-linkedin-open-graph-image):

> LinkedIn's content cache presently stores website information for approximately 7 days before the crawler will revisit the site.

There looks like there is no *instant* way to clear the cache, but to wait seven days, remove the media and re-add it.

Comment: 2018 checking in, appending a query string still works

Answer (score 3):

Appending a query string to the URL no longer works, so you'll have to wait 7 days.
But if you really need to share your URL with the medias you want, you'll have to go with a custom API call.

From the [LinkedIn developer docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) :

> The first time that LinkedIn's crawlers visit a webpage when asked to
>   share content via a URL, the data it finds (Open Graph values or our
>   own analysis) will be cached for a period of approximately 7 days.
>
> This means that if you subsequently change the article's description,
>   upload a new image, fix a typo in the title, etc., you will not see
>   the change represented during any subsequent attempts to share the
>   page until the cache has expired and the crawler is forced to revisit
>   the page to retrieve fresh content.
>
> **If you make API calls that directly provide the content to be shared
>   rather than by a URL that requires analysis, LinkedIn will always use
>   the values you provide.**

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Visit https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

Step 2: Enter your URL and click on Inspect, You will see the updated preview image

Step 3: Now try sharing your URL on LinkedIn

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a way to force linkedin to fetch a fresh version of the page. Just create a redirect to your destination page and share the redirect page.

For example:

If your page that you want to share is: http://stackoverflow.com

Create a redirect for a page: https://stackoverflow.com/share-li to go to http://stackoverflow.com

And then share the https://stackoverflow.com/share-li on linked in. This way linkedin will think it's a new page and it'll get a fresh page version.

It's easy to do if you're using wordpress, just install a redirection plugin like this one for example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress these steps work for me:

1. In the home page I've **removed the featured image** and add it as a simple image on the header of the page
2. I've created a redirect page in my blog like (mydomain.com/social) that redirects all requests to my blog (mydomain.com)
3. Share the blog again in the social networks and everything will be ok

It's done =D

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, there is none as of now. We are investigating what it would take to expose a similar feature. Please stay tuned. We'll announce it on the developer site at http://developer.linkedin.com.

Comment: It has been 1 and half years and nothing happened. For some reason we have spanish sentences for our domain and we cant reset/flush it. We had to use domain.com?linkedin as data url to get correct messaging.

Comment: Getting on for 2 and a half now... is this still being reviewed, Adam?

Comment: Three years later, still nothing?! Seriously—Facebook offers a delinter: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: March 2015 Still Nothing. LinkedIn peoples, get your act together!

Comment: I am very surprised that such a basic issue has not been resolved.

Comment: It's been so long without this function my friend..I will tell you all about it when I'll see you my friend. 2nd June, 2015.

Comment: No solution yet after 4 years?

Comment: Just had to deal with this issue today, appending the query string still works