# Getting old image while sharing page in LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

We have updated `og:image` but still in LinkedIn we are getting the old image.

Is there any way to clear the catch for LinkedIn?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't clear the Cache LinkedIn is using like Facebook or Google+.

But you can add a new query parameter to the url you are sharing to let LinkedIn fetch new data:

`http://mydomain.com/myarticle/?v=1` or something else like `http://mydomain.com/myarticle/?foo=bar`

Comment: I've tried adding a custom query parameter `&customDebugQueryParameter=1` but the LinkedIn Cache didn't update for me.

Comment: Apparently using a query param no longer works...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240800/how-to-clear-linkedin-share-cache#answer-30837358