# How to update Linkedin Open Graph Image?

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I need to update the Open Graph Image for linkedin when being shared. I changed it on Facebook and Plus but not on Linkedin. Is there any workaround on this?

I've tried adding a new link via this site with no luck http://beta.beantin.se/clearing-linkedin-link-sharing-preview-cache/

Answer (score 5):

LinkedIn's content cache presently stores website information for approximately 7 days before the crawler will revisit the site.

We are in the process of creating more self-service tools for the developer community, but until those tools are completed, you will need to wait for the cache period to expire, which will force LinkedIn's crawler to revisit the page.

Comment: Any update on these self-service tools for the developer community?

Comment: Is there self-service tools are there.