# Wordpress: Meta description, Embeb Youtube

Tags: wordpress, youtube, seo, embed

I'm a newbie to wordpress and having a hard time solving this problem wordpress.

Problem 1:
  I change the meta-description in my website but everytime i post a link on my facebook/LinkedIN i keep getting the old description, im currently using Yoast SEO plugins.

Problem 2: 
 Im trying to resize the youtube video in my website. i've done this steps so far and isnt working.
 [embed width="300" height="300"]...(youtube link)..[/embed]

I've tried searching this problem but i just cant solve them. Can anyone help a newbie to solve this problem? you're my only hope.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the first problem:

I assume you've changed the meta description of your website's homepage in the 'titles and meta's' section of the Yoast SEO settings.

If you've verified the `og:description` tag was updated correctly in the source of your page and Facebook is still not picking it up, you might need to force update Facebook's cache of that page using the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). There's a small article about it in the Yoast [knowledge base](http://kb.yoast.com/article/82-facebook-sharing-updated-details).

It seems LinkedIn doesn't have a way of clearing social cache. In this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985659/how-to-update-linkedin-open-graph-image), a senior engineer at LinkedIn claims they crawl your cached pages about every seven days for changes.