# How to clear the cache of LinkedIn sharer manually

Tags: caching, share, linkedin-api

At using share function via LinkedIn API, one and the same picture is transfered  for each page of the website http://hrm.mysitedemo.co.uk
The picture is cached on the server.
The address of this picture on server is: [link](https://media.licdn.com/media-proxy/ext?w=180&h=110&f=c&hash=L6lA3LkDV6GW%2FoLLxGYqQFfumzY%3D&ora=1%2CaFBCTXdkRmpGL2lvQUFBPQ%2CxAVta9Er0Vm4nlUX2w8o9KuFqEK_qkRIC5fXTWHiGHDuucrlICu2KJOcZq-8p0JtLW5fxVgvA7D_Hy62S8U)
Address that leads to share dialog window is : [link](https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://hrm.mysitedemo.co.uk/?title=%D0%A8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%20HRM%20-%20%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%C2%BB%20%D0%A8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%20HRM&summary=&source=)
Could you please tell how to to clear the cache manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear Linkedin Share cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240800/how-to-clear-linkedin-share-cache)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Content shared via LinkedIn is cached by LinkedIn's servers for a period of ~7 days.  There is presently no way to manually clear the cache other than waiting for it to expire.

One possible short-term work-around is to modify your URL with a "garbage" parameter at the end of it, e.g. http://example.com/mypage.html?donothing=1

Provided your site does not change the content displayed based on the parameter you append, LinkedIn will see that as a different URL and you won't get the old cached version.

Comment: Sometimes it seems that Linkedin designers once opened a book titled "how to pointlessly annoy users and developers and prevent them from using your service" and has been following it by the letter ever since

Comment: Adding a suffix parameter works for me (tested March 2017).

Comment: Works for me, as does dropping 'www'

Comment: I just added `?_` at the end of the URL and it worked like a charm. The URL looked like `https://example.com?_` so not too bad

Answer (score 11):

LinkedIn provides **Post Inspector** which obviously clears the preview cache.

Just debug your cached url in https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try passing the &summary="Your short description" in the url, as BBC does:

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.com%2Fnews%2Fworld-europe-35602288&title=Ankara%20blast%3A%20Turkey%20PM%20says%20Syria%20Kurds%20to%20blame&summary=Turkey%27s%20prime%20minister%20says%20the%20deadly%20bombing%20in%20Ankara%20was%20carried%20out%20by%20Kurdish%20YPG%20militia%20based%20in%20Syria%2C%20and%20nine%20people%20have%20been%20arrested.&source=BBC

This way it wont look to load it from your page's OG tags and it wont get cached. Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I've just found a way to force linkedin to fetch a fresh version of the page. Just create a redirect to your destination page and share the redirect page.

For example:

If your page that you want to share is: http://hrm.mysitedemo.co.uk

Create a redirect for a page: http://hrm.mysitedemo.co.uk/share-li to go to http://hrm.mysitedemo.co.uk

And then share the http://hrm.mysitedemo.co.uk/share-li on linked in. This way linkedin will think it's a new page and it'll get a fresh page version.

It's easy to do if you're using wordpress, just install a redirection plugin like this one for example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Similar to this solution, for us the trick was to use a URL shortener and pasting the short URL in. The shortened URL worked straight away and cleared the cache for the original URL!

Comment: This still works. Create a bit.ly link, paste the link into a status update and wait for the preview to load. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the link didn't refetch because I had a RewriteRule (to force www) with `[L,R=301]` in .htaccess. Changing it to simply `[L,R]` made the preview change.

Answer (score -5):

There is a way to clear the cache. Just share the link again making sure you post  to at least one group and to your update. It will update the cache :)

Answer (score -5):

Go to https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/
Insert URL of your page and click "Inspect".
That's all)

Comment: This appears to be a dupe of Jan Kolar's answer.