# Request URL not found while posting articles on linkedin

Tags: sitecore, share

Can someone please let me know when the below "Request URL Not Found" error comes up? I copied an article URL and pasted it to post in LinkedIn. And it gave me this error. The article belongs to the website that I have developed. The issue went away when I cleared the cache by appending a dummy query string to the end of the URL, like http://...?dono=1. Is this the only way to clear cache? My website authors find it difficult to post articles sometimes because of this cache issue and I wanted to make it easier for them. Also I noticed some extra quotes in the OG:title of the article, like ''. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Linkedin servers cache this info for 7 days.

Option 1: 
You can add a query string to your open graph URL:

`?Updated=Sitecore.Context.Item.Statistics.Updated`

option 2:
Try passing the &summary="Your short description" in the URL, as BBC does. This has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35477710/2263758)