# Very old LinkedIn Cache won't flush

Tags: linkedin-api

When sharing http://www.innovationservices.philips.com/ via an AddThis LI share button. Very old ... more than one year old ... images get loaded into the share popup. As I can see from googling this is LI cache, but that's not supposed to be older than ~7 days? Source: this forum and LI official replies.

Is there allready a solution to this. I'm willing to try adding a dummy parameter to my url, but this cahce is waaaay older than a week + I need the help of developpers for this + I'm not sure how this affects SEO (the meta tag solution)?

EDIT: I added google tags to the url, no effect (..?utm_source=wom_invite_mail&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=WOM)

Is there a better way?

Tnx

Jaspert

Answer (score 0):

Apparently LinkedIn is aware of this issue but haven't yet fixed it. See this question below.

[How to clear Linkedin Share cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240800/how-to-clear-linkedin-share-cache)